# How can I use the rails console in a non-rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-console

My project is not a web server. I'm using ActiveRecord and ActiveSupport. I'd like to also have the rails console. How can I do this without generating an entire rails app (and/or, what's the most minimal way to do this?)

Answer (score 15):

Of course, there's no such thing as "rails console in a non-rails app".

What rails console essentially is, however, is just an IRB session with your app classes loaded. So you can do the same by running

```
irb -rapp.rb
```

where `app.rb` is your "environment" file which loads most/all of the classes. You know, the one with all the `require` lines.